# Insert data into two different, but connected tables in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a register page for an MVC project. I want to add user information to a SQL database but, in the database I created two different but connected tables, `person` and `address`. `addressId` is a foreign key to the `person` table. I  don't know how to add to person info to both the `person` and `address` table at the same time.

[image _person][image: 1]

[image _address][image: 2]

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework (4.8 or lower) or .NET Core (2+ / 3+) or .NET (5 / 6)? Are you already using an ORM package such as Entity Framework or EF Core?

Comment: Where, specifically, is it you're stuck? Are you at least completing the `INSERT` into your table `Person`, and then just not sure how to use the generated primary key of said `INSERT` for the next `INSERT` into the `Address` table? What code do you have so far?

Comment: Side note: What if a person lives on a corner building? or if you want to store both work address and home address for the same person? This is a classic case of a many-to-many relationship and not one-to-many.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [stored procedure](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp) that will take all parameters that are needed for both records and perform the `insert into` commands for both tables. You will also need to [wrap a transaction](https://www.sqlshack.com/transactions-in-sql-server-for-beginners/) around the insertion logic, so if one of the inserts succeeds but the other fails, then your db will safely roll back and notify you about the error. Otherwise your transaction can be committed.